# Which file containts ALL_PROXY variable?

Tags: 12.10, proxy

I wonder which file contains ALL_PROXY variable which is being set by Network Manager so I could update it manually.

Answer (score 2):

All the proxy variables are stored in `/etc/environment` file, if you've set the proxy using Network Manager.

If you do not find it there, it can be in either of the following files:

- `~/.bashrc`
- `/etc/bash.bashrc`
- `/etc/bashrc`
- `/etc/profile`
- `~/.bash_profile`
- `~/.bash_login`
- `~/.profile`